# SQLITE foreign key delete not working

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I have done

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

and it's still not working. Tables:

```
tbl_one {
  user_id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  description text,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tbl_two (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
}

tbl_two {
  id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
}
```

Now deleting a user from tbl_two should delete the entry in tbl_one but it does not sqlite version is 3.5.6.

Comment: What's the actual `DELETE` query you're running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key constraint enforcement was added to [SQLite 3.6.19](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) (read first paragraph of section 2). Prior to that version, the statements could be parsed and compile, but with no effect.